# Create heatmap with categorical data in python(Seaborn)

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I'm trying to create a heat-map using Seaborn that shows the instances of type combinations in a DataFrame containing all Pokemon data.

```
poke_df.head()

    NationalNo  Name        Type            Type_1  Type_2  HP  Total
0   001         Bulbasaur   [Grass, Poison] Grass   Poison  45  318 
1   002         Ivysaur     [Grass, Poison] Grass   Poison  60  405
2   003         Venusaur    [Grass, Poison] Grass   Poison  80  525
```

Here is what I have, though the output looks is nowhere near what it's supposed to.

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import sys
import re
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
%matplotlib inline

sns.set()


plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
#flights = poke_df
flights = pd.pivot_table(poke_df, index="Type_1", columns="Type_2",fill_value=0)
sns.heatmap(flights)
```

The picture included(made in tableau) is more-or-less what I'm going for.

[image: Desired result]

Comment: Maybe  `pd.pivot_table(df, index="Type_1", columns="Type_2", values="Name",aggfunc=lambda x: x.value_counts().count(), fill_value=0)` and `sns.heatmap(flights,cmap='Blues')` ?